# Memory Allocation In Derived Class MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, mfc

I have an external component that gives an object, let's say A.
Somewhere in the code I have this:

```
A            *p;
ObjContainer *pBigOne;
...
p = pBigOne->GetAPointerToSomethinOfTypeA();
```

now, inside A, there's a protected method (let's use some imagination and assume it's named ProtectedMethod()) which I want to call, but obviously I can't.
To workaround this, I've written a class B like follows:

```
// B.h
class B : class A
{
     public:
          B();
          ~B();
          bool MyMethodIWantToCall();
}

// B.cpp
B::B(){}
B::~B(){}
bool B::MyMethodIWantToCall()
{
   return ProtectedMethod();
}
```

Changing the code up above:

```
B            *p;
ObjContainer *pBigOne;
...
p = (B *)pBigOne->GetAPointerToSomethinOfTypeA(); // (*)
p->MyMethodIWantToCall();
```

I'm able to get what I want, but a workmate pointed me to the fact that this could lead to some memory nasty error because B is bigger than A. To confirm that, we've added a member to B, initialized it to something and inspected with the VS2010 watch. In VS2005 uninitialized variables start with a value of 84**..., here we got a very random one.

So, I have two questions:
1) When I'm at (*), why I have to cast? Shouldn't be the same type?
2) Is my workaround definitely safe?

**EDIT**

3) Is there a safest way to do this?

Comment: 1) It's simple logic, all B are A, but not all A are B. Therefore conversion from B* to A* is automatic, but the other way around requires a cast. 2) Definitely safe? No, you're breaking the rules of C++. Probably safe? Yes. Ugly hack for which you should know better? Definitely.

Comment: @john: 1) You're right, sometimes I forget the theory. 2a) Why I'm breaking the rules? 2b) What exactly mean with "Ugly hack for which you should know better? Definitely"?

Comment: 3) The assumption behind this question is that you are not able to modify A? If you are then I would just redo your design. You shouldn't want to call protected methods like this.

Comment: The rule you are breaking is that you are taking something that is an `A` object and pretending it's a `B` object.

Comment: You are using ugly tricks to circumvent the design that the author of `A` intended. I'm not saying you shouldn't ever do something like this. But it's better to improve the design of your classes so that they are in step with what you want to do.

Comment: 3) Technically yes, I'm able to change the source code even if it's a third party dll. The problem is that I have to recompile it. Honestly I don't understand why they put a useful method like this as protected.

Comment: Then the simple thing to do would be to change it from `protected` to `public`. That's much better than the trick above.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to recompile the dll, but you could just change private to public in the dll's header file.

Comment: @Michael You cannot. The access modifier is part of the decorated name. Changing the header will cause a linker error when trying to look up the now public method.

Comment: @IInspectable : right, thanks for pointing this out.